# File descriptor 3 (pipe:[34331]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5424: /usr/sbin/grub-probe

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.01 Server with LVM support.

When I execute `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get this error in many lines:

```
    File descriptor 3 (pipe:[34331]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5326: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
    File descriptor 3 (pipe:[34331]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5326: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
    File descriptor 3 (pipe:[34331]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5326: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-64-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-64-generic
    File descriptor 3 (pipe:[34331]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5410: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
    File descriptor 3 (pipe:[34331]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5410: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
    File descriptor 3 (pipe:[34331]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5410: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
```

Should I worry about this situation and do researching how to fix these errors?
What is the reason of them?

Comment: A similar question was answered over in unix.stackexchange.com here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212958/grub-install-file-descriptor-3-leaked-on-vgs-invocation - apparently these messages are harmless.